# Show/Hide an Input Field based on a conditional when making an Addon

Tags: python, add-on

I am writing a Blender Add-on which takes properties from configuration file and generates a tree based on the customization. The Add-On allows tweaking of certain properties, most notably whether the tree is monopodial (one canopy) or sympodial (multiple canopies).

If the tree is sympodial, I want the user to be able to select how many canopies are present in the Add-On. If the tree is monopodial, I want the fields to either be hidden or greyed out/locked for editing.

I've tried something like

```
row = box.row()
row.prop(scn, "Tree_Form")
if (tree_form == "Sympodial")
    row = box.row()
    row.prop(scn, "Num_Canopies")
```

But I haven't had success. Admittedly, I am a complete novice to Python and Blender Add-Ons in general.

Comment: Based on guesswork re your code snippet, you want something like `if(scn.Tree_Form == "Sympodial"):`  Don't forget the colon  after the if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
row = box.row()
row.prop(scn, "Tree_Form")
if scn.Tree_Form == "Sympodial": # the ':' is required
    row = box.row()
    row.prop(scn, "Num_Canopies")
```

Comment: Wow. How did I not look to see that I needed a colon at the end? Thanks so much!

Comment: I myself, was stuck on `.prop`s and such.